# how to add up repeating number by one with JS?

Tags: javascript, replace, repeat

I guess I ask this question wrong, unfortunately, all the submissions did not exactly what I needed was simply a replacement of (to the nth number...):

```
var temp = '1 1 <br>random text</br> 1 1 <br>random text</br> 1 1 <br>random text</br> 1 1';
```

to: (but also keeping text+tags as they are before)

```
var temp = '1 1 <br>random text</br> 2 2 <br>random text</br> 3 3 <br>random text</br> 4 4';
```

Comment: From where are you getting the string and what have you tried ?

Comment: `<nr>` isn't a valid tag, if it's supposed to be one. Also, you're better off generating all the HTML yourself instead of doing lots of string manipulation

Comment: @Bojangles Who said it's HTML? It's not valid XML either fwiw but OP could be using a different format.

Comment: @Benjamin Good point. I saw JavaScript and a tag and instantly though "Ah, it's HTML, but wrong"

Comment: Now that you have changed your question considerably, why don't you show us what you have tried and tell us the problem that you are facing so that we can help correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on the considerably changed question**

See [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Javascript

```
function modify(string) {
    var n = 0;

    return temp.replace(/\b1(\s+)1\b/g, function (all, whitespace) {
        n += 1;

        return n + whitespace + n;
    });
}

var temp = '1 1 <br>random text</br> 1 1 <br>random text</br> 1 1 <br>random text</br> 1 1';

console.log(modify(temp));
```

Output

```
1 1 <br>random text</br> 2 2 <br>random text</br> 3 3 <br>random text</br> 4 4
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gd6sT/)

Answer (score 1):

Except that your markup seems to be **incorrect**, you could use a loop and count up an iterator upto a limited number:

```
var items = 3;
var temp = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= items; i++) {
    temp += "<nr=" + i + ">lorem ipsum<nr=" + i + ">";
}

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: `i<items+1` could probably be `i<=items` , it's pretty identical to wurkfeks (now deleted answer) from 12 minutes ago by the way (in case you didn't get a chance to see it). I'd like to see OP clarify on the actual problem first though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good point, updated the `loop`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following. There is a fiddle at the bottom.

```
var temp = '<nr="1">lorem ipsum<nr="1">\
            <nr="1">lorem ipsum<nr="1">\
            <nr="1">lorem ipsum<nr="1">';

var tags = temp.split('            ');
temp = "";
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    var tmp = tags[i].replace('<nr="1">', '<nr="'+(i+1)+'">');
    tmp = tmp.replace('<nr="1">', '<nr="'+(i+1)+'">');
    temp += tmp;
}
console.log(temp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcYhZ/

Answer (score 1):

If the input could be anything and isn't something you are constructing yourself, then a regular expression is your best bet.

```
var n = 0;
var rx = /(<nr=")1(">[^<]*<nr=")1(">)/g;
var result = temp.replace(rx, function(whole, one, two, three){
    n += 1;
    return one + n + two + n + three;
});
```